# Flutter: Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, vscode, dart

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio Code para programar en flutter y la extensión Dart. Mi problema es que al ejecutar el proyecto y que se vea en el telefono virtual (El cual lo implemento con Android) studio, no me muestra tal, y en el log me sale el mensaje "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"

Buscando posibles soluciones, una era ejecutar en el cmd flutter doctor, adjunto foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como observan, hay tres problemas y la verdad no se como solucionarlo.

Por lo que pregunto como resolver el error que me da flutter.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Al parecer esta indicando extensiones que hacen falta en Visual estudio y ahí te las indica, ademas de tener conflicto con la versión de Java que tienes instalada, actualiza la versión de java que tienes actualmente y no olvides agregarlo al Path, es muy importante.